# Special symbols used in syntax definition

Tags: sql, syntax

I always see syntax definition of sql clauses as the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123.aspx

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name 
   {
    type_name[({precision[.scale]})][NULL|NOT NULL]
   {DROP DEFAULT 
   | SET DEFAULT constant_expression 
   | IDENTITY [ ( seed , increment ) ]
   } 
| ADD 
   { < column_definition > | < table_constraint > } [ ,...n ] 
| DROP 
   { [ CONSTRAINT ] constraint_name 
   | COLUMN column }
] }
< column_definition > ::= 
   { column_name data_type } 
   [ [ DEFAULT constant_expression ] 
      | IDENTITY [ ( seed , increment ) ] 
   ] 
   [ROWGUIDCOL]
   [ < column_constraint > ] [ ...n ] ]
< column_constraint > ::= 
   [ NULL | NOT NULL ] 
   [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] 
   { 
      | { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE } 
      | REFERENCES ref_table [ (ref_column) ] 
      [ ON DELETE { CASCADE | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT |SET NULL } ] 
      [ ON UPDATE { CASCADE | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT |SET NULL } ]
   }
< table_constraint > ::= 
   [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ] 
   { [ { PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE } 
      { ( column [ ,...n ] ) } 
      | FOREIGN KEY 
        ( column [ ,...n ] )
        REFERENCES ref_table [ (ref_column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
      [ ON DELETE { CASCADE | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT |SET NULL } ] 
      [ ON UPDATE { CASCADE | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT |SET NULL } ] 
   }
```

I know the basic meanings of the signs like "|", but where I can get a full explanation of all these signs such as "{", "[", etc?

Answer (score 5):

It's called Backus Naur form, or more specifically Extended Backus Naur form, which is meant to be more human readable and less formal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form goes over it thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

- Pipe means "or"
- Curlies mean "block can be repeated"
- Squares mean "clause is optional"
- Parens are real SQL

Comment: @Bort is certainly more technically correct than I.  I was trying to keep the CS out it.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this however, Curlies do **not** mean "block is optional" Curlies mean the block can be repeated. e.g. `{ <column_definition> } ` in a `CREATE TABLE` statement because the number of column definitions is not limited to 1. An optional block than can be repeated would be `[ { <block> } ]`.